# Upload directory and its sub directories and contents using VB.NET over FTP

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, ftp

I want to make a VB.NET software in which we can select folders and add them in a listbox. These folders and their contents are to be uploaded to a FTP site at a certain amount of time. My question is that what's the code to upload folders and its contents to FTP site. The listbox only contains the main directory locations. There maybe multiple directories in the listbox. Button 3 is the uploadnow button which later on I will connect to the timer. Button 2 is for selecting the directories.

So far I have achieved this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class SYNC

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim dialog = New FolderBrowserDialog()
        Dim dir As String
        dialog.SelectedPath = Application.StartupPath
        If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog() Then
            dir = dialog.SelectedPath
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir))
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Someone please reply back it is very important for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) has the recursive transfer built-in.

Use the [`Session.PutFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles) like:

```
' Setup session options
Dim mySessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With mySessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Ftp
    .HostName = "example.com"
    .UserName = "user"
    .Password = "mypassword"
End With

Using mySession As Session = New Session
    ' Connect
    mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)

    ' Upload files
    mySession.PutFiles("d:\foldertoupload\*", "/home/user/").Check()
End Using
```

See a [full example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#example).

---

Note that the `Session.PutFiles` (and the assembly overall) has synchronous interface (calls are blocking). So you need to execute the code from a separate thread, not from the GUI thread. Otherwise your interface will be unresponsive, while the transfer is proceeding.

To provide a progress feedback to the user, use the [`Session.FileTransferProgress` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress) and the [`FileTransferProgressEventArgs.OverallProgress` property](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_filetransferprogresseventargs).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: so this code will upload all contents and sub directories to ftp? btw thanks a lot for helping

Comment: also is there a option to set a particular time at which the selected folders will be uploaded or sync?

Comment: Yes it will upload the folder recursively. Scheduling an upload is a completely different task for a completely different question. If you are going to post one, make sure you specify, if the upload should happen, while your application is still running; or at any time in future.

Comment: yes scheduling isnt a problem i can just use a timer, i have the idea for that. Just one more help, how do i use progress bar for this code? Please help me out with that also

Comment: thanks a lot i shall give it a try. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to use the `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` class.

This is an untested-by-me example I found here (modified to use `Using` statements):
http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/VB/Visual-Basic-Code-Snippet-Upload-file-to-FTP-Server.html

---

```
''' <summary>
''' Methods to upload file to FTP Server
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_FileName">local source file name</param>
''' <param name="_UploadPath">Upload FTP path including Host name</param>
''' <param name="_FTPUser">FTP login username</param>
''' <param name="_FTPPass">FTP login password</param>
Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String, ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
    Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

    ' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

    ' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

    ' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    ' after a command is executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False

    ' set timeout for 20 seconds
    _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000

    ' Specify the command to be executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    ' Specify the data transfer type.
    _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

    ' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

    ' The buffer size is set to 2kb
    Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
    Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

    ' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    Using _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()

        Try
            ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            Using _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
                ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
                Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

                ' Till Stream content ends
                Do While contentLen <> 0
                    ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                    _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
                    contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Loop

                ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
                _Stream.Close()
                _Stream.Dispose()
                _FileStream.Close()
                _FileStream.Dispose()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: but isnt this just for file uploads? i require to upload directories and their sub directories on ftp along with all files in them